# Why does not cross-referencing of exercises work with `exsheets`?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, exercises, exsheets, tags

I am trying to use `cleveref` package to create custom referencing scheme for exercises created using `exsheets`. I customize cross-referencing of floats and equations very well using codes similar to the one below.

The output of the code below does not show any correct referencing to any question. Even debugging using `\SetupExSheets{debug=true}` shows that questions have not been tagged.

My source code

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{cleveref}

    \crefformat{question}{Question. (#1)}
    \crefrangeformat{question}{Questions. (#1) to (#2)}
    \crefmultiformat{question}{Questions. (#1)}{ and (#1)}{, (#1)}{ and (#1)}
    \crefrangemultiformat{question}{Questions. (#1) to (#2)}{ and (#1) to (#2)}{, (#1) to (#2)}{ and (#1) to (#2)}


\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets[points]{format=\bfseries, number-format=\itshape}            
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=\thesection.(qu[A]), counter-within=section}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}
\SetupExSheets{debug=true,auto-label={false},ref-cmd={\cref},label-format={#1}}


\begin{document}


\chapter{My Chapter}



\section{Section 1}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:1}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[question]{qu:2}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:3}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[question]{qu:4}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:5}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[question]{qu:7}
    Solution
\end{solution}



\section{Section 2}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:6}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[question]{qu:7}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:8}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[question]{qu:9}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:10}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:10}
    Question
\end{question}


\cref{qu:1,qu:2,qu:3,qu:4,qu:5}

\cref{qu:1,,qu:2,,qu:3,,qu:4,,qu:5}

\cref{qu:1,qu:6,qu:9,qu:2,qu:3,qu:4,qu:5,,qu:10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We use `\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thesection.(\Alph{question})}`. We can edit the representation as we wish. A more generalized case could be:

`\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\the<parent label><type of seperation>(\<type of numbering>{question})}`

The definition we write here must match the one we write by `counter-format` option in `\SetupExSheets`. Otherwise, the equation tag could be something like 1.3 while `\cref` output could be 1.III.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets[points]{format=\bfseries, number-format=\itshape}            
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=\thesection.(qu[A]), counter-within=section}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}
\SetupExSheets{debug=true,auto-label={false},ref-cmd={\cref},label-format={#1}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{question}{Question #2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{question}{Questions #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{question}{Questions #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{question}{Questions #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thesection.(\Alph{question})}

\begin{document}


\chapter{My Chapter}



\section{Section 1}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:1}
    Question
\end{question}


\begin{solution}
    \label[solution]{sol:1}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:2}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[solution]{sol:2}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:3}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[solution]{sol:3}
    Solution
\end{solution}



\section{Section 2}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:4}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[solution]{sol:4}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:5}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[solution]{sol:5}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:6}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:7}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:8}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[solution]{sol:6}
    Solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
    \label[question]{qu:9}
    Question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    \label[solution]{sol:7}
    Solution
\end{solution}


\newpage
\cref{qu:1}

\cref{qu:1,qu:2,qu:3}

\cref{qu:4,,qu:5,,qu:6}

\cref{qu:1,qu:2,qu:3,qu:5,qu:6,qu:9}

\cref{qu:2,qu:3,qu:5,qu:6,qu:7,qu:8,,qu:9}

\cref{qu:1,qu:2,qu:3,qu:5,qu:6,qu:7,qu:8,qu:9}


\end{document}
```