# Why does not cross-referencing of end nodes work with `enotez` and `cleveref`?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, endnotes, enotez

It does not seem that `cref` works with `enotez`. The output refers to the chapter number rather than the number of the end note.

I had similar issue in this question: [Why does not cross-referencing of exercises work with `exsheets`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448276/why-does-not-cross-referencing-of-exercises-work-with-exsheets)
. It seems that the solution for `exsheets` does not work for `enotez`, because `question` is an environment while `\endnote` is a command

[image]

My source code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=DodgerBlue3, linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{enotez}
% This package allows for the use of end notes

    \setenotez{mark-format=\tiny, list-name=End Notes of Chapter \thechapter,backref}
    \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\thechapter.\alph{endnote}}

    \DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}{
        heading=\chapter*{#1},
        % Spacing
        notes-sep=0.5\baselineskip,
    %
        % Styling of the printed end notes
    %
            % Notes
            format=\normalfont,
    %       
            % Numbering
            number-format=\normalfont,
    %
        % Notes numbering
        number=#1\hspace{3mm}
                                                    }


\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{endnote}{End Note #2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{endnote}{End Notes #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{endnote}{End Notes #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{endnote}{End Notes #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{\noindent This is a sample text for testing purposes}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{My Chapter}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 1 \label[endnote]{en:endnote1}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 2 \label[endnote]{en:endnote2}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 3 \label[endnote]{en:endnote3}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 4 \label[endnote]{en:endnote4}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 5 \label[endnote]{en:endnote5}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 6 \label[endnote]{en:endnote6}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 7 \label[endnote]{en:endnote7}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 8 \label[endnote]{en:endnote8}}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 9 \label[endnote]{en:endnote9}}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}



    \cref{en:endnote1,en:endnote2,en:endnote3}

    \cref{en:endnote4,,en:endnote5,,en:endnote6}

    \cref{en:endnote1,en:endnote2,en:endnote3,en:endnote5,en:endnote6,en:endnote9}

    \cref{en:endnote2,en:endnote3,en:endnote5,en:endnote6,en:endnote7,en:endnote8,,en:endnote9}

    \cref{en:endnote1,en:endnote2,en:endnote3,en:endnote5,en:endnote6,en:endnote7,en:endnote8,en:endnote9}


    \printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found the in [Cleveref won't work with enotez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395662/cleveref-wont-work-with-enotez?rq=1)

```
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \enotez_endnote_mark:n #1
      {
        \int_gincr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
        \quark_if_no_value:nTF {#1}
          {
            \refstepcounter {endnote}
            % \show \theendnote
            % \cs_gset:cpx {@currentlabel} {\theendnote}
            \enotez_write_mark:xn
              { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int }
              { \theendnote }
          }
          {
            \cs_gset:cpn {@currentlabel} {#1}
            % \cs_gset_eq:NN \theendnote \@currentlabel
            \enotez_write_mark:xn { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int } {#1}
          }
        \bool_if:NT \l__enotez_disable_bool
          {
            \int_gdecr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
            \addtocounter {endnote} {-1}
          }
      }
    \ExplSyntaxOff


Full code

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=DodgerBlue3, linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

    \usepackage{enotez}

            \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\thechapter.\alph{endnote}}
            \setenotez{list-name=End Notes of Chapter \thechapter}
            \setenotez{backref=true}

        \DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}{
            heading=\chapter*{#1},
            % Spacing
            notes-sep=0.5\baselineskip,
                % Default=0.5\baselineskip
        %
            % Styling of the printed end notes
        %
                % Notes
                format=\normalfont,
        %       
                % Numbering
                number-format=\normalfont,
        %
            % Notes numbering
            number=#1\hspace{3mm}
                                                        }



        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \cs_set_protected:Npn \enotez_endnote_mark:n #1
        {
            \int_gincr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
            \quark_if_no_value:nTF {#1}
            {
                \refstepcounter {endnote}
                % \show \theendnote
                % \cs_gset:cpx {@currentlabel} {\theendnote}
                \enotez_write_mark:xn
                { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int }
                { \theendnote }
            }
            {
                \cs_gset:cpn {@currentlabel} {#1}
                % \cs_gset_eq:NN \theendnote \@currentlabel
                \enotez_write_mark:xn { \int_use:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int } {#1}
            }
            \bool_if:NT \l__enotez_disable_bool
            {
                \int_gdecr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
                \addtocounter {endnote} {-1}
            }
        }
        \ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{endnote}{End Note #2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{endnote}{End Notes #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{endnote}{End Notes #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{endnote}{End Notes #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{\noindent This is a sample text for testing purposes}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{My Chapter}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 1} \label{en:endnote1}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 2} \label[endnote]{en:endnote2}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 3} \label[endnote]{en:endnote3}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 4} \label[endnote]{en:endnote4}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 5} \label[endnote]{en:endnote5}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 6} \label[endnote]{en:endnote6}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 7} \label[endnote]{en:endnote7}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 8} \label[endnote]{en:endnote8}

    \sampletext \endnote{My End Note 9} \label[endnote]{en:endnote9}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}


    \cref{en:endnote1}

    \cref{en:endnote1,en:endnote2,en:endnote3}

    \cref{en:endnote4,,en:endnote5,,en:endnote6}

    \cref{en:endnote1,en:endnote2,en:endnote3,en:endnote5,en:endnote6,en:endnote9}

    \cref{en:endnote2,en:endnote3,en:endnote5,en:endnote6,en:endnote7,en:endnote8,,en:endnote9}

    \cref{en:endnote1,en:endnote2,en:endnote3,en:endnote5,en:endnote6,en:endnote7,en:endnote8,en:endnote9}

    \AfterNextEndnotesList{A sample of text that comes before end note list}
    \AtNextEndnotesList{A sample of text that comes after end note list}
    \printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```